# How to override in Kotiln Volley JsonObjectRequest class?

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

I'm writing a Kotlin app that has a class. I need that class to extend JsonObjectRequest, since I need to override the function

```
override fun parseNetworkResponse(response: NetworkResponse?): Response<T>
```

That's because I need to interpret in Kotlin the HTTP response code the server is sending.

However, I admit to being new to Kotlin and haven't managed to figure out how to extend the JsonObjectRequest class. I keep running into silly compiler issues.

Can someone provide a quick example of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of iteration, i managed to finally figure it out. Posting it here since it may be useful to others -

```
class DataRequest(
    method: Int,
    uri: String,
    jsonObject: JSONObject,
    listener: Response.Listener<JSONObject>,
    errorListener: Response.ErrorListener
) :
    JsonObjectRequest(method, uri, jsonObject, listener, errorListener)
{
    override fun parseNetworkResponse(response: NetworkResponse): Response<JSONObject>
    {
        try
        {
            val jsonString = String(
                response.data,
                Charset.forName(HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers))
            )
            return Response.success(
                JSONObject(jsonString), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response)
            )
        } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException)
        {
            return Response.error(ParseError(e))
        } catch (je: JSONException)
        {
            return Response.error(ParseError(je))
        }

    }
}
```